# Time complexity of trigonometric and inverse trigonometric function

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, mathematical-analysis

What is the time complexity of
1.cos(x)
2.acos(x)
3.acos(cos(x))
Please answer

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of this site. So please fix your question to allow a meaningful answer, and show that you have put some effort into finding an answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity refers to algorithms.
The is no such thing as the time complexity of a function.

Depending on the function $f$, you could ask about the time complexity of an algorithm that, given $x$, computes $f(x)$.

Since in your case $x$ and $f(x)$ can be irrational numbers you'll have to be more precise and specify exactly what the algorithm should compute (are you looking for an approximation?) and what encoding is used for the input and the output.